# Parameter/storage type for a C++11 lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, closures

In C++11, how do you declare a function that takes a lambda expression as an argument?  I can find plenty of resources online for declaring lambdas or taking them as template parameters, but what I'd really like to do is be able to make use of lambdas as easy-to-declare callback handlers, similar to what's made possible by closures in JavaScript and code blocks in Objective-C.

Essentially, the classic C++ construct I want to replace with a lambda is something like:

```
class MyCallback {
public:
    virtual ~MyCallback() {}
    virtual void operator(int arg) = 0;
};

void registerCallback(const std::shared_ptr<MyCallback> &);

void foo(void) {
    int a, b, c;
    class LocalCallback: public MyCallback {
        int a, b, c;
    public:
        LocalCallback(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
        void operator(int arg) { std::cout << (a+b+c)*arg << std::endl; }
    };
    registerCallback(std::shared_ptr<MyCallback>(new LocalCallback(a,b,c)));
}
```

which would be simplified into:

```
void registerCallback(/* WHAT GOES HERE? */);

void foo(void) {
    int a, b, c;
    registerCallback([=](int arg){std::cout << (a+b+c)*arg << std::endl; })
}
```

So, what goes where I have written `/* WHAT GOES HERE? */`?

EDIT: This is for the purpose of storing a callback to be called back later, rather than for it being immediately consumed and called.

Comment: Using local types as template arguments isn't legal in C++03. Some compilers allow it as an extension though.

Comment: The advantage of a lambda is that it makes writing callbacks easier. You don't specifically write code that will be used with lambdas, you just write code that will take a `function` argument and the caller can use (or not) a lambda as they like.

Comment: @barnes53 The code I posted doesn't use local types as a template argument. MyCallback is a global, and the local type is being wrapped in std::shared_ptr<MyCallback>.  I use this pattern at work all the time, which is why I'm interested in the way C++11 makes it better. :)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi yes, which is exactly why I was asking this question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually `const std::function<void(int)> &` or `std::function<void(int)>`.

I'm not sure what the verdict is on whether `std::function` should be passed by const reference or by value. Probably by value is fine, especially since you're going to copy it anyway to store.

In case it isn't clear in the middle of all that syntax, `void(int)` is a function type, and `std::function<T>` means approximately, "a functor with the same signature as functions of type T".

Lambdas themselves have *anonymous* types. There is no way to name the type of your lambda expression, and the types of different lambda expressions with the same signature are different:

```
auto foo = [=](int arg){std::cout << (a+b+c)*arg << std::endl; };
auto bar = [=](int arg){std::cout << (a+b+c)*arg << std::endl; };
// foo and bar have different types, accessible as decltype(foo), decltype(bar)
```

Hence the need for `std::function`, which basically is a type-erasing wrapper to gather together different functors with the same signature into a common type. It's the bridge between static polymorphism with templates, and the dynamic polymorphism you need if you want to register a callback, store it for later, and then call it without having "remembered" the original type.

Comment: Thanks.  As is typical, I came across std::function about 30 seconds after posting my question, but your answer is way better than what I'd have written.  Also accepting it for the `decltype()` stuff and the fuller explanation of how lambdas and function-types work in C++11. (Or, I will accept it when SO lets me...)

Answer (score 7):

```
void registerCallback(const std::function<void(int)>& callback);
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a function template. There are a variety of good reasons to, such as better behaviour when overloading (overloading on `std::function` is painful):

```
template<typename Functor>
void registerCallback(Functor&& functor);
```

(You can also accept the parameter as `Functor functor`, that's not too important.)

If the code needs to e.g. store the `functor` later on, *then* that will likely be held inside an `std::function`. Where you want to avoid `std::function` is in function parameters.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that the implementation be kept visible to anything that makes use of it (i.e. in the header file)?  Or is C++11 finally able to keep templatized methods' implementation details hidden?

Comment: @fluffy : Yes, that requirement holds true. But does that really matter?

Comment: @ildjarn It does if I don't want to expose the implementation in a public header file, or if I want this to be a virtual method on an interface, not to mention all the other edge conditions with shared libraries and other situations where templatized methods just plain don't work.

Comment: @fluffy : That's not an answer, that's just begging the question. What advantage is there to hiding the implementation? And there are no situations where "templatized methods just plain don't work" unless you're already violating the ODR, in which cast the non-templatized methods are also in UB-land.

Comment: @ildjam Not everyone provides libraries that are only used for internal use or for open source. Most of what I work on is for private implementations for libraries that other people use. Also, not all work is done on platforms where dynamic linkers work entirely sane - I do a lot of work on obscure embedded systems. And, finally, a private implementation of a pure-virtual method still cannot be done in a templatized way unless you add another layer of indirection.  But this is all beside the point - I would rather not use a templatized method, and that should be all there is to it.

Comment: @fluffy The implementation doesn't have to do much, it can forward to something else -- taking care of details. If instead the public interface accepts an `std::function` the burden of those very details are put on the caller. Sometimes the error can be quite obscure. (On the other hand taking care of those details usually mean something like concept checking and/or traits. I don't know of a ready-made solution for the Callable concept/trait.)

Comment: @LucDanton Sure, but then I have to write forwarding methods for every type it can expect to take, so why not just settle on a single method and be done with it? `std::function` appears to be pretty darn flexible in what it can accept and convert automatically, so why not let that handle all the complexity that would introduce instead?

Comment: @fluffy You missed the point of having a function template (with again a minimal body to avoid any objection with the visible implementation). By the way the problem with `std::function` is that it's *too* lax.

Comment: @LucDanton Okay, could you perhaps edit your answer to provide that insight then? The answer as written just says "do this," but doesn't give any reason why a std::function parameter is a bad idea. If I'm missing the point, then surely other people would too.

Comment: @fluffy : If you care about performance at all (and don't otherwise need persistence of the function/functor), `std::function<>` is a bad idea. If you need template argument deduction for function/functor signatures, `std::function<>` is a bad idea. But these are not specific to your question, they're universally-understood issues regarding `std::function<>`, and `boost::function<>` before it.

Comment: @ildjarn How universally-understood can they be if people are suggesting `std::function`'s use for the top answers on this question? And what do you suggest as the alternative for safely storing a callback/event handler/etc? Please try to be constructive instead of just telling me how wrong I am.

Comment: @fluffy : If persistence is _not_ needed, then template functions are the alternative, as Luc suggested. You appear to be confused, and I'm just trying to rephrase what Luc is already saying; if you're still confused (and pointlessly defensive to boot), then I'm quite happy to leave my +1 for Luc here and give up.

Comment: I wrote the answer short (and am still considering keeping it that way) because the question is short. I *could* write more about the proper use of `std::function` and functors but I have no way to know if that's relevant for your purposes given the code you posted (not that I need more -- all of this is fine to me). I can only give you a very generic and general guideline to a non-specific question. It's true that I've been wondering if we do need in fact a "When *not* to use `std::function`" FAQ to link to such questions.

Comment: @ildjam I'm only confused because my question implied that I wanted persistence. As such I still don't see how this answer was relevant to my question, because I was still expecting an explanation for why using a templatized method was better than a `std::function`.  I'm not being defensive, I am genuinely asking for an explanation for this answer, because the whole reason for asking questions on sites like this is to get answers that are useful for *everyone*. I guess I'm done here.